# Data displayed in wrong format when using adodb-php with sql server on ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, adodb-php

I have an old website running in php on windows, connected to sql-server through adodb library. The data saved to the DB is converted to the following form: `TrÆ°Æ¡ng Thá»‹ Ãnh Tuyáº¿t`, but when I select it, the data will display correctly as follows: `Trương Thị Ánh Tuyết`.

That website was working fine until I needed to switch to running on Ubuntu. It's still the same data, but when selected, it's still displayed as `TrÆ°Æ¡ng Thá»‹ Ãnh Tuyáº¿t`. Can you tell me the cause and how to fix it?

Here is the example code:

```
create database test
use [test]
create table users (name nvarchar(100))
insert into users (name) values ('TrÆ°Æ¡ng Thá»‹ Ãnh Tuyáº¿t')
```

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'vendor/adodb/adodb-php/adodb.inc.php';
include 'vendor/adodb/adodb-php/adodb-errorhandler.inc.php';

$db = ADONewConnection('mssqlnative');
$db->connect('localhost,1433','sql','sql@12345','test');
$sql = "select top 1 name from users";
$array = $db->getAll($sql);
print_r($array[0][0]);exit;
```

output on windows: `Trương Thị Ánh Tuyết`

output on ubuntu: `TrÆ°Æ¡ng Thá»‹ Ãnh Tuyáº¿t`

Comment: This seems like a character encoding issue. In SQL Server the `nchar` or `nvarchar` data types are Unicode (generally UCS-2 format, although they'll be UTF-16 format on a database using an *_SC/Supplementary Characters collation). When inserting or updating data on nchar/nvarchar columns you should be using National Character string literals, i.e.: `N'Trương Thị Ánh Tuyết'` instead of `'TrÆ°Æ¡ng Thá»‹ Ãnh Tuyáº¿t'`

Comment: but is there a way to handle the data display properly? because all the old data is saved like that

Comment: If all of your old data is already like that then it's effectively broken. If it's consistently broken you *might* (unlikely) be able to recover it but that's not really an exercise for SO readers.

Comment: I can recover but it will take a long time to process. If there is no other option then i have to do it. Thank you.